# Managing content of all messages sent out by application

Tags: c#, twilio, resx, mailgun

We have an application that contains several components (a web application, windows services, a web API, etc.) that send out messages to the users of the application via email (MailGun), SMS (Twilio), and automated phone calls (Twilio). All of these messages contain dynamic information that is inserted when the message is actually sent (ex. First name, Username, Timestamps, etc.).

All of the raw text for the messages is stored in format strings in .resx files in a project that is shared between all of the components. A sample string could look like `"Hello {0}, you have a notification!"` where `{0}` is replaced with the first name of the user at run time using `string.Format`.

This structure has led to having hundreds of text resources that are somewhat hard to maintain. Is there a better method/architecture to manage these types of resources or to handle dynamic communications? Or are there any tools/libraries out there that could be helpful for streamlining this type of functionality?

Comment: Can you store the text in a database?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While I have no experience in C# to offer up, I have worked on large scale Ruby on Rails applications and the closest equivalent I can think of when dealing with many strings with interpolations was internationalisation.

In Rails this is handled by supplying a yaml file which contain keys that can contain other keys (thus scoping the messages to certain areas) and the template strings.

While using this sort of approach would lead to reducing the number of files, this one file may then go through regular changes, so your trade off is there.

Just an idea though. Let me know if it helps at all.